# Accessing a loaded Table in drop()

Tags: javascript, p5.js, import-from-csv

I am trying to load a simple CSV file in my sketch through the `drop()` function in p5. I can successfully 'get' the file and call `loadTable()`, however I would like to do something with the loaded table automatically, and for some reason it seems like I have to let the `drop()` function completely finish before being able to access the table.

My little test sketch 'gets' a file that is dragged onto the canvas, loads it into a table, and attempts to print out the `getRowCount()` immediately after loading. This returns 0.... so I also set up a function to run `getRowCount()` when the mouse is clicked, and this works as expected.

My test CSV file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NOluhKiqMxZy10s3dAFLsHLLjoAtV6GT

I only partially understand why this is happening, and I definitely don't know how to get around it. I've been teaching myself Javascript and p5, so I don't know the terms that I need to search to understand what is happening here...

```
var myTable;

function setup() {
  var canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas.drop(getFile);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}

function getFile(file) {
    myTable = loadTable(file.data);

    // Do something with the table *when* I drop it...
    console.log("In getFile function: " + myTable.getRowCount());

    // Doesn't work either...
    extra(myTable);
}

function mouseClicked() {
    console.log("On mouse click " + myTable.getRowCount());
}

function extra(table_) {
    console.log("In extra function: " + table_.getRowCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend always looking in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference) when you have questions about how P5.js works.

[Here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadTable) is the reference for the `loadTable()` function. It says:

> This method is asynchronous, meaning it may not finish before the next line in your sketch is executed. Calling loadTable() inside preload() guarantees to complete the operation before setup() and draw() are called.
>
> Outside of preload(), you may supply a callback function to handle the object:
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> loadTable(filename, options, [callback], [errorCallback])
> loadTable(filename, [callback], [errorCallback])
> ```

You would need to provide a callback function that is triggered when the `loadTable()` function is finished **asynchronously** loading the table.